# Php post to Twitter timing out

Tags: php, curl, twitter

I'm trying to use a php library to post to twitter.

This code:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, $options);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
if (curl_errno($curl)) {
    throw new TwitterException('Server error: ' . curl_error($curl));
}
```

Is producing this error:
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'TwitterException' with message 'Server error: connect() timed out!' in /home/a8905333/public_html/php/Twitter.php:267 Stack trace: #0 /home/a8905333/public_html/php/Twitter.php(104): Twitter->request('statuses/update', 'POST', Array, NULL) #1 /home/a8905333/public_html/edit_events.php(35): Twitter->send('$strEventTitle') #2 {main} thrown in /home/a8905333/public_html/php/Twitter.php on line 267

It's on 000webhost and I've checked that cUrl is enabled so it should be good I think. Is this a coding error on my part or the by product of using a free host like 000?

Comment: There MUST be more code than that - I believe that all calls to the Twitter API require oAuth now

Comment: There is about 5000 more lines of code including the oAuth etc. Want them? Error is called from line 267 http://pastebin.com/S8DPD7mU,